# urlencode filter is not working in django templates

Tags: django, templates, urlencode

I am using django under Apache. When I use `urlencode` in django template, its not at all enoding some thing like this `{{value|urlencode}}` Here is my complete anchor tag

`<a href="/mysite/comment/{{i.comment_id|urlencode}}">Comment</a>`

Can some one help on this? Is there any way to get rid of this?

Thanks in advance - Vikram

Comment: In the code you included, you're not even attempting to use `urlencode`...

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question.. After including it also, its not encoding

Comment: You say "not working", but you fail to explain how...

Comment: urlencoding an integer returns the integer unchanged

Comment: @Ignacio: Not working as in its not encoding

Comment: Hey bradley is there any way to encode integer?

Comment: What does that even mean? Integers are already valid in URLs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `urlencode` filter only encodes characters that are unsafe to have in a URL. If you want to encode *all* characters then you will need to write or find a different filter for that.

Answer (score 5):

As per the django documentation - / is not escaped in default case.
To escape / or other characters as well, use the optional parameter as

```
{{ value|urlencode:"" }}
```

more details - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-urlencode